# perl: doesnt exit without pressing "enter"

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Term::ReadKey;

sub input_worker {

    local $SIG{'KILL'} = sub { threads->exit(0); return;};

    while (1) {
        if (defined(my $char = ReadKey 0, *STDIN)) {
            print "$char";
        }
    }

    return;
} ## end sub input_worker

my $in_thr = threads->create(\&input_worker);
sleep 5;
my $rc = $in_thr->kill('KILL')->join();
print "$rc\n";
```

This program wont exit by itself and just hangs. 
It will only exit after pressing "enter"

How can i make it so that it will exit by itself after 'kill' is signaled

P.S. I dont want to use detach();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing signals and threads is a bit of a challenge, simply because `$thread->kill` doesn't actually use real signals (since signals are sent to processes, not threads). Which is just as well, because if it did, `SIGKILL` can break things.

Even when talking about 'normal' signals - you will have slightly unexpected behaviour, because of perl's handling of them See: [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29) . It's not impossible to use, but you need to be aware of the caveats involved.

But the root of the problem is - that the signal is handled safely, which means perl waits until a suitable moment to process it. It will not do this during a 'read' operation, so the signal processing will get deferred.

I think likely what is happening here is your `ReadKey` is not a nonblocking operation like you think it is. With reference to the [`Term::ReadKey`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm) manpage

> ReadKey MODE [, Filehandle]
>   Takes an integer argument, which can currently be one of the following values:

```
 0    Perform a normal read using getc
-1   Perform a non-blocked read
>0   Perform a timed read
```

So what it does instead is - starts reading from `STDIN`, and blocks (ignoring signals) until you press enter. At which point it runs your signal handler.

Given what you're trying to do here - I would suggest you don't want to use signals at all, and instead - just use a shared variable.

Something like this:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $done : shared; 

sub input_worker {
    while ( not $done ) {
        if ( defined( my $char = ReadKey( -1, *STDIN ) ) ) {
            print "$char";
        }
    }
    return;
} ## end sub input_worker

my $in_thr = threads->create( \&input_worker );
sleep 10;
$done++;
my $rc = $in_thr->join();
print "$rc\n";
```

Will terminate after the timeout, and because it's doing nonblocking reads, it'll bail out on time, without input.  You should note though - this thread is going to be 'spinning' looping rapidly waiting to see if input has been pressed - so it's not very CPU efficient. (a small delay in the cycle helps immensely there, say 0.1s).